# Rails server not starting- how do I resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails server command, but getting multiple error messages. Please advise- how do I trouble shoot and resolve? tks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    46: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    45: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    44: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    43: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    42: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    41: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    40: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    39: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    38: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    37: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    36: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `tap'
    35: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
    34: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
    33: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
    32: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    31: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    30: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    29: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    28: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    27: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    26: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    25: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    24: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    23: from /Users/name/Development/Projects/movie_reviews/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    22: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    21: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    20: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    19: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    18: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    16: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    15: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    14: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    13: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    12: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    11: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    10: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     9: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     8: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:158:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
     7: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `execute'
     6: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
     5: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:38:in `block in updater'
     4: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:24:in `reload!'
     3: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `load_paths'
     2: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `each'
     1: from /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `load': /Users/name/Development/Projects/movie_reviews/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end' (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: You can troubleshoot this by reading the error (" unexpected end-of-input, expecting \`end'"). You can resolve this by fixing the `SyntaxError` (add the `end` that is missing)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I checked the routes.rb file and it does have an 'end'. Pls see-  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies do
    resources :reviews
  end

Comment: You need 2 ends (one for each `do`). `do...end` forms a block so a `do` without a matching end is an unclosed block which will cause a SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

Check the last line from your error log

```
/Users/name/Development/Projects/movie_reviews/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end' (SyntaxError)
```

You're missing an end somewhere in your `routes.rb` (possibly around line 4)

You can check if there is any syntax error on the file using

```
ruby -cw config/routes.rb
```